# Hiding Markers in Array - GOOGLE MAPS API V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I am having problems with hiding markers, my goal is for example if I were to click the control named Manila, the markers in Makati, and Mandaluyong will be hidden. (Note: Manila, Makati, Mandaluyong are cities in the Philippines.

Here is my code, Ive searched through the internet and use setVisible(false), used the .Hide() but nothing works, please help.

This is my .js file

```
var map;
var manila = new google.maps.LatLng(14.600657, 120.98215);
var makati = new google.maps.LatLng(14.55027,  121.03269);
var mandaluyong = new google.maps.LatLng(14.577449, 121.034011);

var ManilaPlaces = [ 
['adamsonuniversity',14.586706, 120.985584],
['staisabel',14.585541, 120.983586]
];

var MandaluyongPlaces = [
['home',14.569827, 121.031156],
];

var MakatiPlaces = [
['shangmakati',14.553999, 121.024725],
];

function ManilaControl(controlDiv, map) {

// Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control
// Setting padding to 5 px will offset the control
// from the edge of the map
controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
controlDiv.style.paddingRight = '5px';

// Set CSS for the control border
var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'none';
controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Manila';
controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

// Set CSS for the control interior
var controlText = document.createElement('div');
controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
controlText.innerHTML = '<b>Manila</b>';
controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

//Manila Markers
for (var i = 0; i < ManilaPlaces.length; i++) {
        var place = ManilaPlaces[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(place[1],place[2]),
            map: map,
            title: place[0],
            zIndex: place[4]
        });
    }

// Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to
// Manila
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
map.setZoom(14);
map.setCenter(manila);
});
}

function MakatiControl(controlDiv, map) {

// Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control
// Setting padding to 5 px will offset the control
// from the edge of the map
controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
controlDiv.style.paddingRight = '5px';

// Set CSS for the control border
var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'none';
controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Makati';
controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

// Set CSS for the control interior
var controlText = document.createElement('div');
controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
controlText.innerHTML = '<b>Makati</b>';
controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

//Makati Markers
for (var i = 0; i < MakatiPlaces.length; i++) {
        var place = MakatiPlaces[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(place[1],place[2]),
            map: map,
            title: place[0],
            zIndex: place[5]
        });
    }

// Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to
// Makati
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
map.setZoom(14);
map.setCenter(makati);
});
}

function MandaluyongControl(controlDiv, map) {

// Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control
// Setting padding to 5 px will offset the control
// from the edge of the map
controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
controlDiv.style.paddingRight = '5px';

// Set CSS for the control border
var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'none';
controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Mandaluyong';
controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

// Set CSS for the control interior
var controlText = document.createElement('div');
controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
controlText.innerHTML = '<b>Mandaluyong</b>';
controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

//Mandaluyong Markers
for (var i = 0; i < MandaluyongPlaces.length; i++) {
        var place = MandaluyongPlaces[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(place[1],place[2]),
            map: map,
            title: place[0],
            zIndex: place[6]
        });
    }

// Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to
// Mandaluyong
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
map.setZoom(14);
map.setCenter(mandaluyong);
});

}   

function initialize() {

//map initialization
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
//controls map default load actions such as zoom, center, disables google maps Default UI
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 14,
center: makati,
disableDefaultUI: true
};

map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);


// Create the DIV to hold the control and
// call the ManilaControl() constructor passing
// in this DIV.
var manilaControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var manilaControl = new ManilaControl(manilaControlDiv, map);

manilaControlDiv.index = 1;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(manilaControlDiv);

// Create the DIV to hold the control and
// call the MakatiControl() constructor passing
// in this DIV.
var makatiControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var makatiControl = new MakatiControl(makatiControlDiv, map);

makatiControlDiv.index = 2;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(makatiControlDiv);

// Create the DIV to hold the control and
// call the MandaluyongControl() constructor passing
// in this DIV.
var mandaluyongControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var mandaluyongControl = new MandaluyongControl(mandaluyongControlDiv, map);

mandaluyongControlDiv.index = 3;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(mandaluyongControlDiv);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: `setVisible` should work, hard to say why it isn't working without seeing the related code.

Comment: Where in your code are you using setVisible, or setting up event listeners for the marker clicks?

Comment: setVisible works on google.maps.Marker objects.  Where are you keeping the references to those?

Comment: sorry about that guys I kinda removed it from the code since it wasn't working anyway so I figured I kinda needed a new code, but the other guy figured it out, Im studying his code now so I can use it on a little project I have, anyway thanks guys its actually my first question here in stackoverflow hope I can also participate in answering, obviously I have a lot to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5vFMD/4/) that exhibits this behaviour.

I've added 3 new arrays which store the google.maps.Marker objects for each city:

```
// Arrays to store markers for each city
var ManilaMarkers = [];
var MandaluyongMarkers = [];
var MakatiMarkers = [];
```

Markers are added to these arrays after they are created (for example:)

```
//Manila Markers
for (var i = 0; i < ManilaPlaces.length; i++) {
    var place = ManilaPlaces[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]),
        map: map,
        title: place[0],
        zIndex: place[4]
    });

    // Add marker to array
    ManilaMarkers.push(marker);
}
```

I've added a new `setMarkersVisible` function (lines 224-228 in the Fiddle) which iterates through an array of google.maps.Marker objects and sets the visibility to true or false depending on the value of the second paramter:

```
function setMarkersVisible(Markers, visible) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Markers.length; i++) {
        Markers[i].setVisible(visible);
    }
}
```

When the click event listeners are called 3 calls are performed to the `setMarkersVisible` function to show and hide the markers depending on which control is clicked. For example if the Manila control is clicked the calls will hide the Makati and Mandaluyong markers but show the Manila markers:

```
// Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to
// Manila
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function () {
    map.setZoom(14);
    map.setCenter(manila);

    setMarkersVisible(ManilaMarkers, true);
    setMarkersVisible(MakatiMarkers, false);
    setMarkersVisible(MandaluyongMarkers, false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really appreciate it, I'll study your code and try to implement it on what I am doing.